# Proj4Leaflet converting coordinates of map center

Tags: leaflet, coordinates, proj4js

Please help me, why this is not working:
`console.log(proj4('EPSG:2180', [map.getCenter()]));`

while this is working fine:
`console.log(proj4('EPSG:2180', [21,52]));`

Console shows [NaN, NaN]...
What should I do with `map.getCenter()` to have coordinates translated?
Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you're wrapping `map.getCenter()` (which returns an instance of `L.LatLng`) into brackets `[`/`]`? That turns it into a one-element `Array`.

Comment: I was trying everything... this: `console.log(proj4('EPSG:2180', map.getCenter()));` is not working too...

Comment: This is working!: `console.log(proj4('EPSG:2180', [map.getCenter().lng,map.getCenter().lat]));`!